# Trouble opening sheet hyperlink vba

Tags: vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to open a sheet of my workbook through a hyperlink with vba.
No troubles to follow a link to a web page or a folder, but I do not succed for a sheet.

Can somebody tell me why please ?

Code :

```
Sub MacroOpen() 

If ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then 

ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End If 

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: why not `sheets("SheetName").activate`? you can always color it blue and underlined to make it look like a hyperlink

Comment: Because I have to follow many hyperlinks to add datas in each linked sheets

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem doing it.

There must just be a little error in your url to the other sheet. The syntax is SheetName!ColumNameAsAsciiRowNumber

so if your sheet name is sheet1 and you want to go to cell A:3
its sheet2!A3

Here is complete code that adds a correct hyperlink to a sheet and then navigates to it

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Sheets("Blad1").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 3), "", Sheets("Blad2").Name & "!A3", "", "my link"
    Cells(2, 3).Select

    If ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
       ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

This is in swedish excel so its sheet names are blad1 and blad2